# Using org-mode babel, how do I quickly export some html soure block to a separate file?

Tags: org-mode, html, babel

I am taking notes on a course in org-mode. I am using HTML source-blocks to write down examples of html code. This serves me because I have text and code in one file and it will be easier to export it to a blog for example.

```
#+begin_src html
  #some html code
#+end_src
```

However, sometimes I want to test the code in a source block and would want to export it to a separate html file. Any tipps on how to achieve this quickly? Exporting via `C-c C-e h o` always exports the whole buffer or the subtree. But I want to export only the code in the source block.

Any tipps on how to do this?

Comment: Search for `Tangling` in the Org mode manual: do `C-h i g (org)Extracting Source Code RET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-c C-v C-t` runs `org-babel-tangle` and exports all code blocks to the current buffer name plus the correct code extension (e.g. html blocks get `.html`, python blocks get `.py`). You can specify the tangled filename with the `:tangle` property at the header, section, or file level.

Run `C-u C-c C-v C-t` to only tangle the current code block containing the point.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized the answer to my question:

hit `C-c '` for `org-edit-special` and then save the buffer to a new file.

Comment: Faster: `C-v C-v C-t` runs `org-babel-tangle`. Add the prefix arg `C-u` to only tangle the current babel block

Comment: @mankoff: please make your comment into an answer (adding some detail if you can).